# Nested model, update_attributes not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, update-attributes

I am having a hard time with what I thought would be an textbook update example. Searched SO but couldn't find the answer.  In short, when I click submit the user_id in the profile model gets wiped out and no other data gets saved. I am using Rails 3.2.2.

Here is what I have...

User model...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :profile_attributes
  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end
```

Profile model...

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :first_name, :presence => true
  validates :last_name, :presence => true
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name
end
```

Users controller...

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.accounts_users.build()
    @user.build_profile()

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end    
end
```

Nested form...

```
<%= form_for @user, :validate => true do |f| %>
  <%=  f.fields_for :profile do |p| %>
    <fieldset>
      <div class="field">
        <%= p.label :first_name %>
        <%= p.text_field :first_name %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= p.label :last_name %>
        <%= p.text_field :last_name %>
      </div>
  <% end %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit 'Edit Profile', :class => "btn btn-large btn-success" %>
        <%= cancel %>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

Edit: I edited the UsersController to include the new action. Why would the new action affect the edit/update actions?

Comment: Alex...you got me thinking and I realized the new/create actions aren't working either.  I posted another question here, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266125/multi-model-nested-form-cant-add-users-to-current-account).  I will come back to this question (and hopefully answers it) once I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem before. Can we see the code for your `new` action? Do you have `@user.build_profile` in there (right beneath `@user = User.new`)? Or is the `new` action working fine?