# Multi-model nested form, can't add users to current account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, multi-tenant

I've searched everywhere for a solution but haven't come up with any.

**The part that works**: My app allows customers to create an account using a nested form.  The data collected creates records in four models - accounts, users, accounts_users (because a user can be associated with many accounts), and profile (to store the user's fname, lname, phone, etc).

**That part that doesn't work**: Once logged in, I want the users to be able to add more users to their account using the form below. I don't receive any errors upon submit but I am brought back to the same form with no additional records created.  Any help would be awesome!

Here is the nested form...

```
<%= form_for @user, :validate => true do |f| %>
<fieldset>
    <%= f.fields_for :profile do |p| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= p.label :first_name %>
      <%= p.text_field :first_name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= p.label :last_name %>
      <%= p.text_field :last_name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= p.label :phone %>
      <%= p.text_field :phone %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit 'Create New User', :class => "btn btn-large btn-success" %>
        <%= cancel %>   
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

The ApplicationController scopes everything to the current_account like so:

```
def current_account
  @current_account ||= Account.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomain) if request.subdomain
end
```

The UsersController

```
def new
  @user = User.new  
  @user.build_profile()
  #current_account.accounts_users.build()  #Edit2: This line was removed

  respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @user }
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  @user.accounts_users.build(:account_id => current_account.id) #Edit2: This line was added
  if @user.save
    # Send Email and show 'success' message
    flash[:success] = 'An email has been sent to the user'
  else
    # Render form again
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Models look like this:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :subdomain, :users_attributes
  has_many :accounts_users
  has_many :users, :through => :accounts_users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :profile_attributes
  has_many :accounts_users
  has_many :accounts, :through => :accounts_users
  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end

class AccountsUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :user
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :phone
end
```

Edit2: It turns out that I had required a password + password_comfirmation validation in the User model which prevented me from adding another user without these fields.  I commented out these validations plus removed the line: current_account.accounts_users.build() in the 'new' action and added the line: @user.accounts_users.build(:account_id => current_account.id) in the 'create' action.

Comment: I think you are not associating current_account with user in create action. Can you try @user = @current_account.users.new(params[:user])?

Comment: Alper - I tried your suggestion but there was no change.  Are you thinking that my code looks good except for your suggestion?  Or, do you have some other thoughts?  I'm pulling my hair out over this one!

Comment: I tried your code, it is working for me, creating new user, except it is not creating any AccountsUser. I modified the create action as i said, and saved _also_ @current_account. Can you provide some log after submitting form? Your model names and relations look a little different and hard to understand to me but i cant see anything really wrong.

Comment: @Alper - I got it to work.  Not sure if this is the right way so if you have any other suggestions, I'm all ears.  Now, of course, I am faced  with other issues (see Edit2 notes) but I'll save them for another question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

"I want the users to be able to add more *users* to their account using the form below." I assume you mean *profiles* (since your nested form is on profiles)?

If that's the case, I think your UsersController's create action isn't associating the profiles with users by using new.

Try this...

```
def new
  @user = User.build
  @profile = @user.profiles.build #build adds the profile to user's associated collection of profiles, but new doesn't

  ...
end

def create
  @user = User.build(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    ....
  end
end
```

If you want the user to be associated with account, then you need to put the new and create actions in the AccountsController and do something similar to nest association of the users and profiles records.

Btw, the reason that it went back to new is because you render new at the end of the create, in case that's also part of the question. Hope that helps!